# While executing PowerShell through batch script I want to store execution status log file for that PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to execute PowerShell inside batch script. It is executing perfectly, but I'm trying to create log file for that PowerShell execution status. It is creating empty file.

I want to store data of PowerShell execution status.

Batch file (`Test.bat`):

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy  RemoteSigned -File 
    C:\Users\rani\Documents\String\Unt1.ps1 "%user%" "%password%" 
    "%path%" >>C:\Users\rani\Documents\B2_Move.txt
```

It is not storing the PowerShell execution data in log file.

Comment: Put the logging inside your Powershell script.

Comment: The code you posted is broken due to incorrect wrapping. Please do not wrap code in arbitrary places when posting a question. We cannot help you when the code in your question introduces additional problems that are not present in the code you're trying to debug. Also, please show your PowerShell script and indicate what output from that script you expect to go into the log file.

Comment: can please send me code for that.How to create log file from invoke-expression and invoke-command

Comment: [Do not use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).